# Concatenate a variable number of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a number of lists called: index_1, index_2, index_3, ...., index_n.
What I want is to concatenate them all in a new list.

My code so far:

```
index_all=[]
for i in range(1,n+1):
    index_all = index_all + globals()["index_"+str(i)]
```

However, I get an error:

> KeyError: index_1

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: This means that there is no variable stored in globals with the name index_1... should there be one?

Comment: Yes, I think there should be one, right?

Comment: Best test: try yourself to access `globals()["index_1"]` via python console

Comment: Please make a full code example, as there seems to be something missing. You say you have lists `list_1` to `list_n`, but I don't see them in your code. Also it is not obvious what `index_all` represents. Why do you need any indices in a list, if you just want to concatenate the lists? Is that the list where you want to append all the contents of the other lists?

Comment: Should it be `globals()["list_"+str(i)]` ?

Comment: If you want to concatenate lists, in Python it should be possible to just do `list_concatenated = list_1 + list_2 + list_3`. Do it in a for each loop if you have a sequence of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use list unpacking

```
cat_list = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    cat_list = [ *cat_list, *globals()['index_'+str(i)] ]
```

Comment: Creating a new list unpacking the elements each time scales really bad both with the number of lists and with the numbers of elements in the lists.

Comment: Use `cat_list.extend(globals()['index_'+str(i)])` or `cat_list += globals()['index_'+str(i)]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use map and filter , and the globals().items() feature:

```
concat_list  =  map ( lambda list_var : list_var[1] , filter ( lambda list_var  : list_var[0].startswith("list"), globals().items()))
```

your concat_list is the list of all items from all lists

Comment: still this means that I want to iterrate over my lists, something like:
`all_lists=[]

for i in range(1,n+1):

    all_lists.append(index_i)`
but that leads us to the same problem, how do I iterrate over these index_i lists?

Comment: you may want to use extend and append these list into one list and then do my solution

Comment: Neither do I, but I was hoping there could be some.

Comment: use extend like so all_lists.extend((list_1, list_2, list_3)) and then my solution

Comment: But that's pretty much the same as the above right? I mean it presupposes that I manually enter my lists. I will work fine if they are 3, but what happens in my case that they are 100? Manually wiritng list_1, list_2,....,list_100 is not a good idea.

Comment: ddor254 assumes that you have a sequence of lists, and why would you not? Accessing the variable names is not really a very elegant solution, and it should not be much more effort to put them in a tuple or list instead of using public variables.

Comment: i've edited my original solution after really understand what he meant .

Comment: Yeah, the updated solution seems to work, my only issues is that it does not maintain the order, i.e. list_1 should be first, list_2 second, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def joinAll(mulist):
     index_all=[]
     for i in mulist:
         for u in i:
             index_all.append(u)
     return index_all

print joinAll(list1)
```

Comment: It looks like I have to manually input the list1, list2, list3 in the function joinAll. Supposing that I have 100 lists: list1 up to list100, this is clearly non functional.

Comment: @lmm since `index_all` is outside of the function, I think there is no use returning it.

Comment: also using `list.extend(another_list)` lets you get rid of the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may just have a naming error, you try to call "index_" + str(i) but your lists are named "list_" + str(i). The following line should work as long as your lists are named list_1, list_2... list_n with no breaks and your n is correct.

```
index_all = [globals()["list_"+str(i)] for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

If you want the lists to be flat you can

```
[item for sublist in index_all for item in sublist]
```

It might be easier if you can avoid using globals() as it will probably be fragile!

Comment: No, just a typo in  the question, sorry my bad. The names of the variables are indeed index_1, index_2, index_3 and I have already tried your suggestion and it won't work